# functional testing with select id in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, testing

In my form, I have several select, all the same name, but different Ids.

```
    <form method="POST" action="/"
          accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <select name="directElimination_fighters[]" class=directElimination_select id="1_1">
            <option selected></option>
            <option value="1639"> Esteban Prohaska </option>
            <option value="1640"> Vicenta Walsh </option>
        </select>
        <select name="directElimination_fighters[]" class=directElimination_select id="1_2">
            <option selected></option>
            <option value="1639"> Esteban Prohaska </option>
            <option value="1640"> Vicenta Walsh </option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="update">
            Update 
        </button>
    </form>
```

I'm making my functional tests, so I do :

```
    $this->visit('/')
        ->select('Esteban Prohaska', '1_2')
        ->press('update');
```

But PHPUnit says:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "1_2"
```

When I add `->dump()`, I can see in HTML the id="1_2" field. So what's wrong with my code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
->select('#1_2', '1639')
```

Comment: Docs says the opposite... the first field should be the value.... https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#interacting-with-your-application

Comment: It seems that when I use class name, it works, but when I use just id, ( because name is always the same [], I get `Unreachable field``

Comment: I'm not sure about 5.1, but I've checked 5.4 dos and the source code of the select method and the first parameter is definitely must be dropdown name or selector. If you're using 5.1, I'd recommend you to check the source code to be sure how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `#` - **#1_2**. It's like in CSS, where identifiers begin with #.

```
$this->visit('/')
    ->select('#1_2', 'Esteban Prohaska')
    ->press('update');
```

By default Laravel treat first parameter of `->select()` as a name of input.